# Html text with framed/bordered words in java textComponent

Tags: java, html, swing, border

The html code in the label below is rendered in a browser as expected.
Well, java API states that "border" is not fully supported, but the padding in
the example doesn't work either.
Although I have little hope, I want to ask whether there is an alternative in
html to draw a border.
What I found comes closest is a one cell table. There the paddding works, but the thinnest border is quite opulent.
Note that I would like to frame only single words, not a whole line or paragraph.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class HtmlLabel extends JFrame {

  public HtmlLabel() {
    setSize(300,200);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setTitle("A JLabel with HTML text");

    JLabel lb= new JLabel("""
    <html>Please give <span style="border:1px solid; background:#D8EAFC;\
    padding:5px">me</span> a frame.</html>""");
    add(lb);
    setVisible(true);
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(HtmlLabel::new);
  }

}
```

Comment: Swing only supports HTML 3.5 and limited CSS, this may be one of those limitations

Comment: *I would like to frame only single words, not a whole line or paragraph.* - then your example should show that. Your current example can easily be implemented with normal text in the JLabel and a Border.  I can't tell exactly what you expect to see when you "frame" only single words in a sentence. I don't know anything about HTML, but maybe other approaches can be used to achieve your desired effect.

Comment: @camickr Yes, your comment on the example is right.  So I updated the code. - The goal is to render the text that it looks like a small button, thus being an eye catcher. Html can paint buttons, but java supports only those buttons which are operable, meaning you can really press them. For a help text, however, I prefer dead buttons. Apart from the html table solution I could also display a graphics file, which I had to create for each and every button then - not very appealing as rather time consuming.

Comment: Try the HTML based <kbd>kbd</kbd> element..

Comment: @Andrew Thompson Thanks for the suggestion, but the tag renders only the typeface of the text to Monospace, both in Firefox and in Java.

Comment: You could always use styles to make it look more button-like. My apologies BTW - I'd have made a quick example of what I mean (and tested it) but my IDE is newly installed and I'm having some problem identifying the Swing packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know where you get your HTML from or how you build it.

Maybe you can use a `JTextPane` with a custom `Painter`:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class TextPaneInsert2
{
    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane.setText("Please  give  me a frame");
        textPane.setEditable( false );

        try
        {
            RectanglePainter rp = new RectanglePainter( Color.BLACK );
            textPane.getHighlighter().addHighlight(7, 13, rp);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {System.out.println(e);}

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(textPane, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        frame.add(textPane, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater( () -> createAndShowGUI() );
    }
}
```

The above code uses the [Rectangle Painter](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/28/rectangle-painter/).

I did a quick change to the `RectanglePainter` to paint both the background and the border:

```
//  Code is the same as the default highlighter except we use drawRect(...)
g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
g.fillRect(r.x, r.y, r.width, r.height);
//g.drawRect(r.x, r.y, r.width - 1, r.height - 1);
g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
g.drawRect(r.x, r.y, r.width - 1, r.height);
```

And I got:

[image]

Note:

1. I added an extra space before/after the word you want to highlight to get extra padding.
2. Also, not sure why I tested with a JTextPane. You can use any text component, so you could use a JTextField as well.

Comment: First of all thank you for taking the time to work on the problem. The result looks very nice. - I have some windows consisting of nothing but a JLabel with a help text and an [OK] button. What I find pleasant in Html is that it does all the formatting (captions, lists, tables, vertical padding) on the spot, so no java code is necessary, and thus the text becomes modification and maintenance friendly. But since JTextPanes "understand" Html, I will consider switching from JLabels to JTextPanes.